# Creating user-friendly installer for Node.js application

Tags: node.js

How can I create a user-friendly installation for my Node.js application? The installer must connect to the MySQL database and exec commands. Can user do it without the Node.js installed? Or have you got any tips how can I provide it? And how about SaaS? I thought about it, but I'm afraid of server and the hard drives. node_modules can be very big. Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to run node-specific code without the user having node installed on there pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most **standard** way to deploy an app in nodejs ecosystem is thru `npm` which **requires nodejs** on the target system.

You must prepare your `package.json` stating all your dependencies and your installation scripts (preinstall and postinstall). Then, you distribute your code artifacts along with the `package.json`. At the target system, you or your users would just copy all your artifacts and run `npm install` and eventually `npm test`.

This is the standard procedure that anyone fluent in nodejs, as many sysadmins are nowadays, is able to easily understand and follow.

**However** if your application is to be used by end users without systems admin experience, or that who migh not have node/npm installed, this is somewhat complicated for them. In that case, you need to provide a simplified installation that includes packaging nodejs with the app.

For ideas; if your app is a kinda desktop app for end users) take a look at `electron` and `electron-packager`. Or if your app can better be characterized as a local server app, a container like `docker` can be worth studying.

Comment: I'll try to make a user-friendly installer in Electron. I'll try to install Node.js via curl or something, I probably even can do it - https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-install-and-use-node-js-and-npm-mac-and-windows/ I'll think about it. Thank you very much!